# Generic Mergesort Works on Integers but doesn't finish with strings?

Tags: java, sorting, merge

For whatever reason, despite the fact that it's entirely generic and works with integers whenever it's tested with strings it seems to skip the last iteration of merging. I've scoured my code for a couple hours now and I can't see why it isn't working correctly so any insight anyone has would be well received!

> import java.util.Iterator; import
>   java.util.LinkedList;
>
> /**  *  * @author paul  */ public
>   class MergeSort> {
>
> ```
> LinkedList<T> theList;
>
> MergeSort(LinkedList<T> toBeSorted) {
>     theList = toBeSorted;
> }
>
> public LinkedList<T> sort() {
>     return trueSort(theList);
> }
>
> private LinkedList<T> trueSort(LinkedList<T> sorting) {
>     if (sorting.size() <= 1) {
>         return sorting;
>     }
>     LinkedList<T> left, right, sorted;
>     left = new LinkedList<T>();
>     right = new LinkedList<T>();
>     int middle = sorting.size() / 2;
>     Iterator<T> sojourner = sorting.iterator();
>     for (int i = 0; sojourner.hasNext(); i++) {
>         if (i < middle) {
>             left.add(sojourner.next());
>         } else {
>             right.add(sojourner.next());
>         }
>     }
>     return trueMerge(trueSort(left),
> ```
>
> trueSort(right));
>       }
>
> ```
> private LinkedList<T> trueMerge(LinkedList<T> left,
> ```
>
> LinkedList right) {
>           LinkedList result = new LinkedList();
>           while (left.size() > 0 || right.size() > 0) {
>               if (left.size() > 0 && right.size() > 0) {
>                   if (left.getFirst().compareTo(right.getFirst())
>   < 0) {
>                       result.add(left.pop());
>                   } else {
>                       result.add(right.pop());
>                   }
>               } else if (left.size() > 0) {
>                   result.add(left.pop());
>               } else {
>                   result.add(right.pop());
>               }
>           }
>           return result;
>       } }

Here's my main java file

> ```
> import java.util.Iterator;
> import java.util.LinkedList;
> import java.util.Random;
>
> /**
> *
> * @author paul
> */
> public class Main {
>
>     public static Random Rand;
>
>     public static int randomNumber(int min, int max) {
>   return min + (int) (Rand.nextDouble() * ((max - min) +
> ```
>
> 1));
>           }
>
> ```
>     public static <T> String getString(LinkedList<T> linkInt) {
>   String s = "";
>   Iterator<T> interLink = linkInt.iterator();
>   for (int i = 0; interLink.hasNext(); i++) {
>     s = s + interLink.next().toString();
>     if (interLink.hasNext()) {
>     s = s + ", ";
>     }
>     if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0) {
>     s = s + "\n";
>     }
>   }
>   return s;
>     }
>
>     /**
>   * @param args the command line arguments
>   */
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>   Rand = new Random();
>
>   LinkedList<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<Integer>();
>   for(int i = 0; i< 100;i++){
>     numbers.add(randomNumber(1,1000));
>   }
>   System.out.println(getString(numbers));
>   MergeSort m = new MergeSort(numbers); //change this
> ```
>
> later to be purely static
>         numbers = m.sort();
>         System.out.println(getString(numbers));
>
> ```
>   LinkedList<String> words = new LinkedList<String>();
>   words.add("Hello");
>   words.add("MY");
>   words.add("name");
>   words.add("Is");
>   words.add("Barthoal");
>   words.add("I");
>   words.add("Enjoy");
>   words.add("long");
>   words.add("beach");
>   words.add("walks");
>   words.add("would");
>   words.add("you");
>   words.add("like");
>   words.add("to");
>   words.add("come");
>   words.add("Join");
>   words.add("me");
>   words.add("in");
>   words.add("my");
>   words.add("StarDestroyer-MobileHome?
> ```
>
> (TM)");
>         System.out.println(getString(words));
>         MergeSort mm = new MergeSort(words);
>         words = mm.sort();
>         System.out.println(getString(words));
>           }
>       }

This outputs:

> 304, 842, 342, 794, 574, 99, 250, 885,
>   408, 387,  899, 73, 391, 883, 771,
>   848, 968, 504, 129, 370,  994, 897,
>   649, 345, 983, 326, 688, 547, 541,
>   567,  777, 987, 201, 326, 298, 959,
>   166, 962, 864, 797,  512, 505, 609,
>   208, 21, 43, 458, 442, 138, 570,  455,
>   442, 516, 294, 406, 310, 215, 212,
>   397, 98,  938, 496, 263, 973, 571,
>   861, 687, 276, 927, 608,  421, 831,
>   820, 510, 68, 172, 504, 8, 976, 992, 
>   68, 497, 33, 233, 607, 587, 611, 695,
>   834, 338,  448, 978, 359, 413, 1, 819,
>   18, 977, 693, 649
>
> 1, 8, 18, 21, 33, 43, 68, 68, 73, 98, 
>   99, 129, 138, 166, 172, 201, 208, 212,
>   215, 233,  250, 263, 276, 294, 298,
>   304, 310, 326, 326, 338,  342, 345,
>   359, 370, 387, 391, 397, 406, 408,
>   413,  421, 442, 442, 448, 455, 458,
>   496, 497, 504, 504,  505, 510, 512,
>   516, 541, 547, 567, 570, 571, 574, 
>   587, 607, 608, 609, 611, 649, 649,
>   687, 688, 693,  695, 771, 777, 794,
>   797, 819, 820, 831, 834, 842,  848,
>   861, 864, 883, 885, 897, 899, 927,
>   938, 959,  962, 968, 973, 976, 977,
>   978, 983, 987, 992, 994
>
> Hello, MY, name, Is, Barthoal, I,
>   Enjoy, long, beach, walks,  would,
>   you, like, to, come, Join, me, in, my,
>   StarDestroyer-MobileHome? (TM)
>
> Barthoal, Enjoy, Hello, I, Is, Join,
>   MY, StarDestroyer-MobileHome? (TM),
>   beach, come,  in, like, long, me, my,
>   name, to, walks, would, you

As you can see, the numbers are fully sorted. The strings seem to have missed the last iteration of merging. So what exactly went wrong?

Comment: I flat out refuse to read that. Format your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String comparison is case sensitive. That is, all uppercase strings will be placed before the lower case ones. Your merge sort algorithm should allow to take an own comparator which could be String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER for your use case.

Comment: Thanks, knowing that I completely rewrote it for static use and overloaded for a comparator. Works great, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine and it sorts correctly. 
You need to understand that upper-case letters are different than lower-case letters. when comparing a "My" wit "beach" you will get that "My" should come before "beach" (because upper-case letters come before lower-case letters).

This is the reason why in your result, all the upper case letters get all words that start with a capital letter are placed at the beginning.

You may want to use the `compareToIgnoreCase()` method (defined on Strings) to compare your string while ignoring the case of the letters.

See details of this method here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String

(And please reformat your code)